# How can I make my code work if the input is already predetermined?

Tags: python, list, function

So I'm trying to assume the grader defines the following variables

```
a to be some int
b to be some float
s to be some string
```

Write a program that prints out exactly the following, where the values in < .... > are replaced by the actual value inside the variables. However, you can only use ONE print statement.

```
// The variable 'a' has value of <a>. //
\\ While the variable 'b' has value of <b>. \\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "<s>". //
```

Example, if a=1, b=1.5 and s='hi', then the expected output is:

```
// The variable 'a' has value of 1. //
\\ While the variable 'b' has value of 1.5. \\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "hi". /
```

Here is my code so far, **which I got through the help of the kind Stack Overflow users**

```
def make_tags(tag, word):
        print("<" + tag + ">" + word + "</" + tag + ">")
```

However, this doesn't work when the variables are predetermined already... what should I change??

Comment: what is the output you want and what is the output you get?

Comment: It really is not clear at all what you are asking and the situation you are describing. What do you mean by "the grader?"

Comment: use `f-strings`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you meant because your question isnt clear enough, but you can use an fstring to achieve a single line print out,

```
a = 1 
b = 1.5
c = 'hi'
str_example = f'this sentance has an int {a}, a float {b} and a string {c}'
print(str_example)
```

my output looks like this,

```
this sentance has an int 1, a float 1.5 and a string hi
```

When you start a string with the letter f before the quotation mark, you can use curly braces to insert variables.

You could create your fstring like this,

```
a = 1 
b = 1.5
c = 'hi'

some_string = f"// The variable 'a' has value of {a}. // \n \\ While the variable 'b' has value of {b}. \\ \n // Lastly, the variable 's' has value of \"{c}\". //"
```

the output would like this,

```
// The variable 'a' has value of 1.
 While the variable 'b' has value of 1.5.
 Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "hi". //
```

You could also use triple quotes like this,

```
a = 1 
b = 1.5
c = 'hi'

some_string = f"""// The variable 'a' has value of {a}. //
\\\ While the variable 'b' has value of {b}. \\\\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "{c}". //"""
```

Your output would look like this,

```
// The variable 'a' has value of 1. //
\\ While the variable 'b' has value of 1.5. \\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "hi". //
```

If it needs to be wrapped in a function you can do something like this,

```
a = 1 
b = 1.5
c = 'hi'

def string_maker(a,b,c):
    return f"""// The variable 'a' has value of {a}. //
\\\ While the variable 'b' has value of {b}. \\\\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "{c}". //"""

print(string_maker(a,b,c))
```

The output will be the same as above.